# Does Powerapps return the delegatable filtered results, prior to performing the non-delegatable filtering on the app?

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I am setting up a large (2000+ records) "task tracking register" using a SharePoint List, and intend to use Powerapps as the UI.

As you would imagine there numerous drop drown fields in the list which I would like to use as a filter within the Powerapp, but being that these are "Complex" fields, they are non-delegatable.

I'm lead to believe that I can avoid this by creating additional Columns in the SharePoint list that use a Flow that populates them with plain text based on the Drop-down selected.

This is a bit of pain, so I'd like to limit the quantity of these helper columns as much as possible.

Can anyone advise if a Powerapps Gallery will initially filter the results being returned using the delegateable functions first, and then perform the non-delegatable search functions on those items, or whether the inclusion of a non-delgatable search criteria means that the whole query is performed in a non-delegatable manner?

i.e.

Filter 3000 records down to 800 using delegatable search, then perform the additional filtering of those 800 on the app for the non-delegatable search criteria.

I understand that it may be possible to do this via loading the initial filtered results into a collection within the app and potentially filtering that list, but have read some conflicting information as to the efficacy of this method, so not such if this is the route I should take.

Answer (score 0):

Delegation can be a challenge. Here are some methods for handling it:

1. Users rarely need more than a few dozen records at any time in a mobile app. Try to use delegable queries to create a Collection locally. From there, its lightning fast.
2. If you MUST pull in all 3k+ of your records, here's my favorite hack. [Collect chunks of your data source then combine into a single collection](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Discussion/Pulling-in-large-ish-SQL-tables/m-p/243777/highlight/true#M71518).
3. If you want the function to scale (and the user's wait time) [you can determine the first and last ID to dynamically build a function](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Discussion/500-item-limit-in-CDM-entity-search-filter-need-to-switch-to-asp/m-p/22980/highlight/true#M9872).

Good luck!